# Element is no longer attached to the DOM error in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

First it is executing else part, then after printing println , it is giving this error. Don't know if it is giving error after coming out of loop. Please help.

```
Opens a page
Check if the new month is available
Downloads new month ex: Oct
Then comes out of loop and should download Sep
```

But after coming out of loop it is throwing above error message.

```
 driver.get("http://www.depreportingservices.state.pa.us/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOil_Gas%2fOil_Gas_Well_Historical_Production_Report");
            //maximizing the window
              driver.manage().window().maximize();

               //WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.id("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue"));

              // Select select=new Select(select);
               List<WebElement> options = driver.findElement(By.id("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue")).findElements(By.tagName("option"));
               //List <WebElement> Element1 = new ArrayList<WebElement>() ;

               for(WebElement option : options){

                  if(option.getText().equals("Sep 2015 (Unconventional wells)")) {

                      driver.get("http://www.depreportingservices.state.pa.us/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOil_Gas%2fOil_Gas_Well_Historical_Production_Report");
                         driver.wait(20000);
                             //options.wait(10000);
                          driver.findElement(By.id("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue")); 

                      System.out.println("old month");
                       break;

                  }
                  else {

                    //  if(option.getText().contains("Oct"))
                      //{
                          System.out.println("Download new month");

                          WebElement identifier = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue']"));
                          Select select1 = new Select(identifier);

                          //select1.selectByVisibleText("Oct");

                         select1.selectByVisibleText("Oct 2015 (Unconventional wells)");

                          Wait(20000);
                          driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl00']")).click();
                          Wait(70000);
                          //Click on File save button
                          driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Button']")).click();
                          //wait time to load the options
                          Wait(20000);
                          driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ReportViewerControl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu']/div[2]/a")).click();
                          //fprofile.setPreference( "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false );
                          //fprofile.setPreference( "pdfjs.disabled", true );
                          Wait(10000);

                         // driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                          System.out.println("Oct month data downloaded in csv format");
                          //driver.navigate().back();


                      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception means that the element you are trying to use is not longer exist in the html.

My guess is that you get the exception on `for(WebElement option : options)` because one of the clicks in the `else` section redirects you to new page or deletes the `options` from the dom. Even if you go back to previous page you still need to find the element again.

You can try something like this

```
List<WebElement> options;
int i = 0;
do
{
    options = driver.findElement(By.id("ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue")).findElements(By.tagName("option"));
    if(options.get(i).getText().equals("Sep 2015 (Unconventional wells)"))
    {
    }
    else()
    {
    }
} while (i++ < options.size())
```

Comment: May I know how to overcome this?

Comment: I think a new page is getting opened, when you are downloading the file, which is deleting `options` from `dom`

Comment: Then how should I make this to happen?

Comment: @user2762008 Replace the `for` loop with the `do while` loop

Comment: @pArAs It's possible, but as I said I'm just guessing, it isn't clear where he gets the exception.

Comment: unfortunately, this replacing also didn't helped :(

Comment: /read the file that value store into String = "Sep 2015 (Unconventional wells)";
        //collect the list
        //array[2].equal(String)
        //if same out
        //else {download}

Comment: Hi, your logic worked, but please help me that in the drop down , there is All in the list. code shouldn't go to else part if the text is All. How to skip all part and check for the next item in the list?

Comment: @user2762008 Change the `else` to `else if()`

Comment: what shall i put in if , for else if block? please could you please be more clear?

Comment: The string you want to do the action on.

Comment: with this work?else
        { if (options.get(i).getText().equalsIgnoreCase("All")){
       --- code }  while

Comment: i see equalsIgnorecase worked, but after downloading oct month, can I extract oct month txt and store it in a txt file and then again compare it with sep month?

Comment: hi right click class file and add a txt file with Sep 2015 string, and can I use that txt file to compare string in the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
    1. don't use wait 
    2. use css and not xpath 
    3 .read about page object design pattern 
    4 try to use this instead of the click 

after you clean your code you can find the problem easily 


    public static WebElement findElement(WebDriver driver, By selector, long timeOutInSeconds, String timeOutMessage) {
            try {
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(selector));

                return findElement(driver, selector);
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(timeOutMessage);
            }
        }

        public static WebElement findElementSafe(WebDriver driver, By selector, long timeOutInSeconds) {
            try {
                return findElement(driver, selector, timeOutInSeconds);
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: i used css, id and name all are failed :( , but didn't changed click to this yet. Please help

Comment: read about page object design pattern , the test should be like a story need to be very easy to read . you need to invest in infrastructure after you read it i will be happy to help you

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, running it waiting for the result

Comment: This is giving error for findElement, Safe in above code:

Comment: The method findElement(WebDriver, By, long, String) in the type stack4 is not applicable for the arguments (WebDriver, By)

Comment: :) happy to hear that

Comment: you can change it for example without any message